# custom icon resolution for static google maps markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Trying to use custom icon as a marker on static google maps, but the resolution seems a bit off on http://test.glossny.com/

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.6926405,-73.9770746&zoom=12&size=1320x600&scale=2&key=AIzaSyBx5AxGjWK0lMs9umPEbMkCLZz5GuqN2pI&markers=icon:http://goo.gl/XsLxAb|Fort Greene, Brooklyn&style=visibility:simplified|hue:0xF7F9FF|lightness:85&sensor=true_or_false](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.6926405,-73.9770746&zoom=12&size=1320x600&scale=2&key=AIzaSyBx5AxGjWK0lMs9umPEbMkCLZz5GuqN2pI&markers=icon%3ahttp://goo.gl/XsLxAb|Fort%20Greene,%20Brooklyn&style=visibility%3asimplified|hue:0xF7F9FF|lightness:85&sensor=true_or_false)

Thanks.